# Sending Instagram DM with API

Tags: ios, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I’m currently trying to find a way of sending Instagram DMs to specific users via an API (im building an iOS app and this is one of the functionality im trying to build). I know there are solutions that currently offer that (like Jarvee or Instazood) however none of them seems to offer an API that will allow me to do that in my own app. Given that Instagram current legacy of Instagram API that seems to allow DM will be discontinued on Dec 1st, I cant seem to find an option that enables me to do that. Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api to send dm's to your user.
It's written in node but you can find other libraries in other languages

Comment: Awesome! Thansk a lot!